# applying a function to the rows of a data.frame

Tags: r, function, shiny, lapply

I have 2 different data.frames both containing data for a calculation. One of them contains a price data which is indexed by date and time (for eg. 12.04.2019 12:00:00). The other one contains different parameters indexed by months( for eg: for month 1 a price is 610, for month 2 the same price becomes 570, etc.) I am using shiny to make a web app that can get 2 files that are mentioned above and do the necessary calculations. I can upload and read the files easily don't have a problem at there. But when it comes to calculations, I have some troubles. First of all, my first data which is indexed by date and time has 8760 rows, each raw has the price data that is needed for calculation. On the other hand my monthly data contains 12 rows. Using renderUI function in the server, I make my app read the data from the monthly indexed one as you can see in the code:

```
     output$gaz1 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz1", "Ocak Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[1,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz2 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz2", "Şubat Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[2,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz3 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz3", "Mart Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[3,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz4 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz4", "Nisan Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[4,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz5 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz5", "Mayıs Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[5,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz6 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz6", "Haziran Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[6,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz7 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz7", "Temmuz Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[7,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz8 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz8", "Ağustos Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[8,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz9 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz9", "Eylül Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[9,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz10 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz10", "Ekim Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[10,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz11 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz11", "Kasım Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[11,4])
     })
    
     output$gaz12 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("gaz12", "Aralık Ayında Gaz Kullanımı", value = aylıkdata()[12,4])
     })
    
     output$fiyat1 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat1", "Ocak Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[1,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat2 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat2", "Şubat Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[2,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat3 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat3", "Mart Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[3,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat4 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat4", "Nisan Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[4,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat5 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat5", "Mayıs Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[5,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat6 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat6", "Haziran Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[6,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat7 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat7", "Temmuz Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[7,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat8 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat8", "Ağustos Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[8,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat9 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat9", "Eylül Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[9,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat10 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat10", "Ekim Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[10,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat11 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat11", "Kasım Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[11,2])
     })
    
     output$fiyat12 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("fiyat12", "Aralık Ayında Gaz Fiyatı", value = aylıkdata()[12,2])
     })
    
     output$bload1 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload1", "Ocak Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[1,3])
     })
    
     output$bload2 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload2", "Şubat Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[2,3])
     })
    
     output$bload3 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload3", "Mart Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[3,3])
     })
    
     output$bload4 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload4", "Nisan Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[4,3])
     })
    
     output$bload5 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload5", "Mayıs Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[5,3])
     })
    
     output$bload6 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload6", "Haziran Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[6,3])
     })
    
     output$bload7 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload7", "Temmuz Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[7,3])
     })
    
     output$bload8 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload8", "Ağustos Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[8,3])
     })
    
     output$bload9 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload9", "Eylül Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[9,3])
     })
    
     output$bload10 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload10", "Ekim Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[10,3])
     })
    
     output$bload11 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload11", "Kasım Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[11,3])
     })
    
     output$bload12 <- renderUI({
       numericInput("bload12", "Aralık Ayında Baseload Üretim Miktarı (MWh)", value = aylıkdata()[12,3])
     })
```

And with using the inputs I read from the monthly data with renderUI, I want to make calculations for each price element of each row of the 8760 row data. I wrote an "if, else if" statement which you can see below:

```
    fun <- function(x){
      if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 1) == TRUE){ x * input$bload1  - (input$gaz1*input$fiyat1) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload1}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman)== 2) == TRUE){ x * input$bload2  - (input$gaz2*input$fiyat2) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload2}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 3) == TRUE){ x * input$bload3  - (input$gaz3*input$fiyat3) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload3}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 4) == TRUE){ x * input$bload4  - (input$gaz4*input$fiyat4) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload4}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 5) == TRUE){ x * input$bload5  - (input$gaz5*input$fiyat5) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload5}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 6) == TRUE){ x * input$bload6  - (input$gaz6*input$fiyat6) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload6}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 7) == TRUE){ x * input$bload7  - (input$gaz7*input$fiyat7) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload7}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 8) == TRUE){ x * input$bload8  - (input$gaz8*input$fiyat8) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload8}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 9) == TRUE){ x * input$bload9  - (input$gaz9*input$fiyat9) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload9}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 10) == TRUE){ x * input$bload10  - (input$gaz10*input$fiyat10) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload10}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 11) == TRUE){ x * input$bload11  - (input$gaz11*input$fiyat11) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload11}
      else if(isTRUE(month(usedata()$zaman) == 12) == TRUE){ x * input$bload12  - (input$gaz12*input$fiyat12) - input$ürtvergi*input$bload12}
      }
```

And with the help of lapply, I wanted to calculate for each row and get the results as a data.frame. The lapply function is this:

```
 Baseload <- reactive ({
      lapply(usedata()$PTF_sayı, fun)
      
      })
```

However, I cannot get the results. What would you guys suggest? Looking forward see your suggestions. Thanks for further help. Have a nice day

Comment: Hi Ahmet, have you tried `apply(usedata()$PTF_sayı, 1, fun)`? Usually, [apply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply) is the way to do these things. A more general comment: you have a lot of repetition in your code (basically everything is copied 12 times). Once you get your code to work, you could try to remove this repetition by making the month a variable, and looping/applying over that as well. That makes your code easier to read and to maintain.

Comment: Hi Bas. Thanks for your recommendations. First of all, I will try to shorten my code as soon as I can get a working app done :) And for the apply function recommendation, I have tried the same apply function as you mentioned above but in the app, I get an error saying "dim(X) must have a positive length". So both apply and lapply does not do my work

Comment: You need to rethink your fun function, and your UI inputs. Then the function could be simplified something like: get month index `monthIx <- month(usedata()$zaman)`, then calculate by position `x * input$bload[ monthIx ]  - (input$gaz[ monthIx ] * input$fiyat[ monthIx ]) - input$ürtvergi * input$bload[ monthIx ]`

Comment: Thanks for the comment zx8754. However, there is still an error. I think the indexing does not work on reactive elemenets.